# How to export and import selected objects to different and separate csv files in blender

Tags: export, import

I'am New to python and i need to
export and import selected objects to different and separate csv files in blender. Every object would been export to separate csv files. I cheek to Google but can't be help.

Comment: Oh nobody to help?